# Unable to access internet from Ubuntu 9.10 VMware guest

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, vmware-workstation

I have a Ubuntu 9.10 VMware guest. I am using the NAT mode. My machine has a valid IP address and I am able to ping the host and the host is also able to ping the guest. I am also able to ping the default gateway (the one specified in the VMware virtual network settings). But I am not able to ping any external website like Google.com. ( name resolution is working fine). Any suggestions/feedback on how to go about troubleshooting this issue ?

Comment: how is name resoloution working fine, have you seen the ubuntu box resolving names? if you ping www.google.com does the name resolve but no ping is sent/returned

Answer (score 0):

You will need a route on your router back to your host. Without knowing more about the setup, your best bet is tcpdumping at the router, host and guest to figure out where the packets are getting lost.